# updated iOS 6.1.2 now I can't archive app xcode

Tags: ios, archive, software-distribution

When I want to distribute my app from XCode I select my device in the list at the top and that enables the option to Archive my application.

I upgraded to iOS 6.1.2 last night and now my device will not show up in the drop down list at the top so I can't archive the app.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to use Xcode 4.6.x with devices that have iOS 6.1.x.

Comment: Vinny has the answer to your question (you don't need to have a device plugged in to Archive).  But check in the organizer under Devices, that your device shows up - you may need to click on "Use for Development" in that section to have your device show up to build against for future debugging.

Comment: But on Xcode Version 4.6 (4H127) 6.1.2 device not connected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to have a device plugged in to Archive. In Xcode click the dropdown next to the *Run* and *Stop* buttons and change the selection from *iPhone 6.1 Simulator* to *iOS Device*. You should then be able to Archive your build as usual.

In order to have your 6.1.2 device show up in the dropdown, you may need to update Xcode to the latest version.

Comment: XCode 4.5.2 was my default.  I reopened with 4.6 and I was able to do what I needed.  Thanks all for the quick responses.